# C# urdu writing not read from database

Tags: c#

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ALIZEE_TROTT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UrduStemmer;Persist Security Info=false; User ID=sa;Password=password");

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from stop_word_list where word_list='کو' ", con);

DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ok");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("not ok");
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question?

Comment: btw, thanks a lot for your password :-)

Comment: Is your column type is `nchar`, `nvarchar` or `ntext`. And second the code file has necessary encoding to represent constant in unicode.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that your column for word_list is one of following type

1. nchar
2. nvarchar
3. ntext

You must precede all Unicode strings with a [prefix N](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/239530) when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server

```
SELECT * FROM stop_word_list WHERE word_list = N'کو'
```

Hope that helps.